# wxpython save and save as,

Tags: python, file, wxpython

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti75w.png)
I am trying to solve the save option but my problem is when I press save button, if the file does not exist, it should show a dialog box to ask for a path/file name and then save the file.

- Sorry for poor English, see the image.

I want it to work as follows:
    1) Open new file and write content (Done).
    2) Save "if it is a new file, the dialog box has to show up".
    3) again press Save "If the file already exist means the dialog box has to disappear and file has to update.

Thanks and regards,
D. Vinay Singh

```
def onSaveAs(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "Text (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        i = dlg.GetFilterIndex()
        if i == 0: # Text format
            try:
                f = open(dlg.GetPath(), "w")
                print(f)
                hole = self.txt.GetValue()
                print(hole)
                f.write(hole)
            except:
                print("Hello")



def onSave(self, event):
    pathtxt = self.txt_1.GetValue()

    f = open(pathtxt,"w")
    hole_1 = self.txt.GetValue()
    f.write(hole_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
**Note: I haven't tested it**

```
def onSave(self, event):
    pathtxt = self.txt_1.GetValue()
    if pathtxt != "":
        if not pathtxt.endswith('.txt'):
            pathtxt=pathtxt+'.txt'

    try:
        with open(pathtxt, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.txt.GetValue())
    except:
        try:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "Text (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE)
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                i = dlg.GetFilterIndex()
                if i == 0: # Text format
                    try:
                        with open(dlg.GetPath(), 'w') as f:
                            f.write(self.txt.GetValue())
                    except:
                        print("Save failed")
                else:
                    print("Save failed - Use .txt file suffix")
        except:
            print("Save failed - Unknown reason")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import os

        def onSave(self, event):
            try:
                f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
                f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                f.close()
            except:
                try:
                    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "Text (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
                    if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                        self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                        self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
                        f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                        f.close()
                    dlg.Destroy()
                except:
                    pass

        def onSaveAs(self, event):
            try:
                dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save to file:", ".", "", "Text (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
                if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                    self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                    self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                    f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
                    f.write(self.control.GetValue())
                    f.close()
                dlg.Destroy()
            except:
                pass
```

Note: self.filename and self.dirname needs to be initiated and tracked at all times.

Comment: Hello altarawy thanks for give the answer but i'm update my content and added an image. Your solution is not solving my problem. Thank you have a nice day

Comment: Before you use the code, assign self.filename = '' and self.dirname = '' in your __ init __ and import os

Comment: @altarawy I've upvoted your answer but you do need to set `self.filename` at the end of both dialogs and perhaps add a note to the answer that `self.filename` needs to be initiated and tracked at all times.